# Ubuntu 12.10 Eclipse IDE opens py file with gedit(default) cant run file from gedit? cant switch default to eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, gedit

I am trying to run a simple 'hello world" py file in Eclipse and the file opens with gedit or gvim and i cant seem to get it to run. So I installed Eclipse and I cant seem to get the py file I select to open in the Eclipse IDE ... attempting to install py dev to fix this

Comment: I ran this as per another question about why eclipse wont run sudo apt-get --reinstall install tzdata-java and it did not seem to do anything to resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eclipse doesn't come by default with a python-editing environment.

You probably want to install the [PyDev](http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html) addon. See the link for how to get it via the eclipse addon manager - it isn't available through the Ubuntu repositories.

EDIT: Re-reading the question, I may have misunderstood. I'm not clear if the question is:

- How to associate `.py` files to be opened with eclipse rather than `gedit/gvim`?
- Why eclipse starts an external editor when you try and open a python file with it? (because it has no python editor, see above)
- Why a python file doesn't run when clicked in the file browser? (because it needs to be marked as executable, and in the hello world case probably exits before you've seen anything)

Comment: Solved :) I can now open my py files in Eclipse. I followed the instructions and it worked fairly well apart from the fact that there is still some configuring to do and I am going to see if I can get it configured from my tutorials. Thanks, chronitis you have been really helpful with this tricky install